# Executing a lisp function from Java

Tags: java, swing, common-lisp, sbcl

I  have compiled Lisp code and I want to make a front end GUI for it. I chose Java swing to develop the GUI. Now I want to call the LISP code (SBCL) from java application! Is there any way to do that? How to execute lisp code from Java?
Thanks

Comment: `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: I will try this. Thank you. Any hints or tips or tutorials?

Comment: The [tag:ProcessBuilder] tag is a good start.

Comment: There is a Common Lisp which directly runs on the JVM: http://abcl.org

Comment: I came to mention exactly what Rainer already said.  Have you tried running your code under ABCL?  That would probably be the easiest route.

Comment: A good start for ProcessBuilder would be the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Today I would have made a rest API that is used by the front end. You can then support having more than one UI (textual shell, backbone.js, ...) and of course have B2B interface available for axiomatization.

Comment: But the lisp code is in SBCL  not common  Lisp

Comment: @HamdaBinteAjmal SBCL is Steel Bank Common Lisp, which is an implementation of the Common Lisp standard.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will look into it as I am not an expert in LISP programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the best solution for you is use:

http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/

You cand find this samples on that web

```
/*
 * Main.java
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2008 Ville Voutilainen
 * $Id$
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
 * as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
 * of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
 */

import org.armedbear.lisp.*;

public class Main
{
    /**
     * This example creates an Interpreter instance, loads our
     * lisp code from a file and then looks up a function defined
     * in the loaded lisp file and executes the function. 
     *
     * The function takes a single parameter and invokes a java method
     * on the object provided. We provide our Main object as the parameter.
     *
     */
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
    try
        {
        Main thisObject = new Main();
        Interpreter interpreter = Interpreter.createInstance();
        interpreter.eval("(load \"lispfunctions.lisp\")");
        // the function is not in a separate package, thus the
        // correct package is CL-USER. Symbol names are
        // upper case. Package needs the prefix, because java
        // also has a class named Package.
        org.armedbear.lisp.Package defaultPackage = 
            Packages.findPackage("CL-USER");
        Symbol voidsym = 
            defaultPackage.findAccessibleSymbol("VOID-FUNCTION");
        Function voidFunction = (Function) voidsym.getSymbolFunction();
        voidFunction.execute(new JavaObject(thisObject));
        }
    catch (Throwable t)
        {
        System.out.println("exception!");
        t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
    return a + b;
    }
}

;;; lispfunctions.lisp
;;;
;;; Copyright (C) 2008 Ville Voutilainen
;;; $Id$
;;;
;;; This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
;;; modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
;;; as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
;;; of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
;;;
;;; This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;;; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;;; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;;; GNU General Public License for more details.
;;;
;;; You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;;; along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
;;; Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.

; we need to get the
; 1) class (Main)
; 2) classes of the parameters (int)
; 3) method reference (getting that requires the class
; of our object and the classes of the parameters

; After that we can invoke the function with jcall,
; giving the method reference, the object and the parameters.
; The result is a lisp object (no need to do jobject-lisp-value), 
; unless we invoke the method
; with jcall-raw. 
(defun void-function (param)
  (let* ((class (jclass "Main"))
     (intclass (jclass "int"))
     (method (jmethod class "addTwoNumbers" intclass intclass))
     (result (jcall method param 2 4)))
    (format t "in void-function, result of calling addTwoNumbers(2, 4): ~a~%" result)))
```

and also an excelent mannual for doing that

Comment: Yes I have done that and I was about to post it. Thanks for the suggestion. Worked like a charm

Comment: Hey. Running abcl lisp functions from Java code loads the files at runtime. Does it mean I will have to ship the .lisp files with the product?

Comment: Hi Hamda, maybe you can compile it to fasl. and execute from the compiled lisp files, I didn't try it yet

Comment: I cant find any code example from Lisp that executes a funtion from Fasl

Comment: Hi again, In this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055589/how-can-i-run-sbcl-code-under-a-unix-like-operating-system-in-a-convenient-way you have how to compile the lisp files to fasl usinc sbcl, maybe you can use this compiled files with abcl, bt I'm not sure